# How to get clients ip in a TCP server?

Tags: python

I have developed a simple TCP chat system, and it works fine. But I need to add a new feature to this Server ie clients validation. I have planned to do by using ip address of clients to validate users. So that I can apply a condition that ""one ip = one user or client"

Comment: TCP does not have clients or servers. TCP sets up peer connections, where each peer is equal and can send, receive or close the connection. Client/server is an application concept. Security by address is a fool's game. You use something like certificates to do that. Ask on [security.se].

Comment: IP addresses are generally not constant: most networks use DHCP to assign them dynamically and reassign them from time to time, and they can easily be spoofed by a malicious actor. Trying to maintain what sounds like a client whitelist is also an administrative nightmare if you have more than 2 users. I agree with @RonMaupin that this is *not* a smart way to restrict users in general and *especially* not a good way to authenticate/identify them.

Answer (score 5):

Do not use IP address as an authentication factor. Use an application layer authentication, many mature implementations exist.

IP address is not secret, not cryptographically strong, can be faked, is not unique (NAT), and is likely to change (renumbering, IPv6 temporary addresses).

IP address can be useful in other ways. Rate limiting, or a risk score of user behavior, or allow listing only certain prefixes. But not for auth itself.

Comment: Then how to make a valid authentication??

Comment: @Sre3edy You can use some form of Password Authentication or Challenge Handshake Authentication.
Using an IP allow list is good additional security measure

Comment: Use an existing authentication protocol like WebAuthn, SASL (XMPP), or Kerberos. If you have no auth, fine, just don't pretend that IP address is authentication.